# Setting cookie for AngularJS translate locale using PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, angular-translate

My app uses Symfony and AngularJS. I have translations some with Symfony itself and some with AngularJS angular-translate. How do I set a cookie or session variable to change language for AngularJS from PHP?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the cookie via PHP:

```
<?php setcookie("_locale", "en"); ?>
```

and retrieve it from angular with ngCookies:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
     // Retrieving the cookie
     var locale = $cookies.get('_locale');
     // Do something with locale
}]);
```